# Android EditText Capital Characters

Tags: android, android-edittext, capitalize

I have an edittext and I want any character that I type in edittext show in Capital letter. I have used this:

> edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);

But it is not working. I want to do it dynamically. Any ideas.

Comment: Here is a solution that is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25571410/922354

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type of hack,Try this:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
          String s=arg0.toString();
      if(!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()))
      {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         edittext.setText(s);
       edittext.setSelection(s.length());
      }
    }
});
```

This should work(don't have time to check)try putting the lines in onTextChanged in afterTextChanged if this doesn't work..

Comment: Thanks Hiral. I will try this one. It seems interesting.

Comment: Well it is returning StackOverflowError. And it has to because setting "edittext.setText(s);" will again call the onTextChangeListener.

Comment: Then try putting it in afterTextChanged and remove from onTextChanged!

Comment: @rizzz86: please see my edited code in answer.it will convert whole string in uppercase even though user enters it in lower case.

Comment: Thanks @Hiral it works now. Added one more line: "edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());" for character sequence.

Comment: @hardPass: means? where is the problem?

Comment: Oh,  it works now. I just saw this in comment. edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());

Comment: @Hiral I think it will convert when user try to write on field but letter will be showing in small case. Is there is way to show only capital letter on soft keyboard?

Comment: It works fine practically . No Issues except we should make the string reverse Thank you

Comment: For me, none of the overrides in the TextWatcher were called. Possibly due to `The documentation states that the key events will only be propagated for the hardware key strokes, not software.`. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425838/edittext-onkeylistener-not-working

Answer (score 13):

You just need to try with **android:inputType** attribute.

As per your requirement, you can include `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

Comment: Thanks Paresh. But I have to do it dynamically through java code

Comment: nothing prevents the User press 'shift' and write a letter lowercased.

Answer (score 4):

For doing it dynamically:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your editText
    android:capitalize="characters"

Comment: this method had deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:capitalize="characters"/>
```

Comment: this is Deprecated: Use inputType instead. [enum]

Answer (score 1):

```
   EditText txt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.textView1);
   txt.SetFilters(new Android.Text.IInputFilter[] {
                      new Android.Text.InputFilterAllCaps()
                  });
```

Comment: `InputFilter.AllCaps()`

Answer (score -1):

you can try this too, if nothing else works

```
String text=editText.getText().toString();
editText.setText(text.toUpperCase());
```

add this code to the onTextChangeListener of EditText