# Not setOnKeyListener nor setOnEditorActionListener working unexpectedly

Tags: android

i am trying to do some thing when user press enter button in the EditText (It is multi lines editText means user can write more than one lines)
simply i want to detect either the enter key pressed
the code used is given below

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
```

and  listener is

```
mBodyText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
                if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "neter presed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it do not show any thing when i press but show **when i long press enter key**

and setOnEditorActionListener is

```
mBodyText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
                if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "neter presed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

it shows nothing when i press enter key and application crashes when i long press the enter key
please help me i am trying it from long time

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425838/edittext-onkeylistener-not-working-solved-with-workaround

Comment: thanks for reply  
but can u suggest me any other option to detect the enter key in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disappointed no one there to Answer my question but i solved it on my own resources
setOnKeyListener was not working because the some of the android devices do not support this but most of them do support
and setOnEditorActionListener caused crashes because i am trying to get data from database and show it in my EditText view on the activity starts
thanks all especially   @isma3l