# Converter app using two edit Text only

Tags: android

I am making a converter app that converts rupees to dollar and vice versa,i want to use two edit text only, i want it to work as when i enter a value in the edit text meant for rupees it should simultaneously show the converted value in the edit text meant for dollar, to be more precise i want that if i want to convert 120 rupees to dollar, as i start entering 120, as 1 it should show the converted value simultaneously in the dollar edit text, followed by 12 and then finally 120.

I have tried-

```
if(editText.isFocusable()==true){

           editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                   str=editText.getText().toString();
                   rs = Double.parseDouble(str);
                   rstodol = rs / 65;
                   str1 = Double.toString(rstodol);
                   editText1.setText(str1);
               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               }
           });


       }


        else if(editText1.isFocusable()==true){

           editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                   str=editText1.getText().toString();
                   dol=Double.parseDouble(str);
                   doltors=dol*65;
                   str2=Double.toString(doltors);
                   editText.setText(str2);
               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               }
           });
       }
```

where am i wrong ?

Comment: Have a look at AsyncTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @COYG AsyncTask is inappropriate here, his calculation is short and can be completed with listeners.

Comment: @bradkratky very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners should be added once, then they perform their task until they are removed.  You are only adding one listener due to your outer `if` block.  Instead, you want to check if the currently selected EditText is `hasFocus()`:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if(editText.hasFocus()) {
            try {
                String str = editText.getText().toString();
                double rs = Double.parseDouble(str);
                double rstodol = rs / 65;
                String str1 = Double.toString(rstodol);
                editText1.setText(str1);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                // invalid string entered
                editText1.setText("");
            }
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(editText1.hasFocus()) {
            try {
                String str = editText1.getText().toString();
                double dol = Double.parseDouble(str);
                double doltors = dol * 65;
                String str2 = Double.toString(doltors);

                editText.setText(str2);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                // invalid string entered
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: One more thing related to it, can we use onKeyListener here ?

Comment: I've always used `TextWatcher`, which I believe is more specific because it reacts to when the text is changed. I don't have much experience with it but it seems onKeyListener is a method of View which detects hardware key input - other answers suggest it's less reliable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425838/edittext-onkeylistener-not-working-solved-with-workaround