# keyListener does not recognise input

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, onkeylistener

I have a KeyListener on an editText like so:

```
tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
tip.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener(){
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        Log.i("debug123", "onKeyListener. event.getKeyCode(): " + event.getKeyCode());

        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            checkInput();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But no softkeyboard-stroke is recognised.?
Only when I left the Activity with the BACK-Button (HardwareButton) the Listener recognises the action.
But from all that I read, this is the way to go if I want to work with user-input at a EditText.

Comment: Use `setOnEditorActionListener` instead `setOnKeyListener` for your purpose

Comment: Check if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425838/edittext-onkeylistener-not-working) is of any help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### setOnKeyListener

> Register a callback to be invoked when a **hardware** key is pressed in
> this view. Key presses in **software** input methods will generally not
> trigger the methods of this listener.

### setOnEditorActionListener

> Set a special listener to be called when an action is performed on the
> text view.  This will be called when the **enter key** is pressed, or when
> an **action** supplied to the IME is selected by the user.

To solve your problem using `setOnEditorActionListener`, please check below:

- Add `imeOptions` and `inputType` to your `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tip"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

- Then add `setOnEditorActionListener` to `EditText`

```
tip.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if ( (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) ) {
            checkInput();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Here,

- `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` handle action from Soft Keyboard (IME)
- `event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` handle enter key from Hardware Keyboard

Comment: No, that does not work for me. I tried the app (with the setOnKeyListener-Solution) on an older smartphone and it worked like expected. But not on my newer phone.

Comment: Can you update your code what have you tried with layout? This should work. It is tested

Comment: upps, I did the layout-part without the input-part. Now it works, thanks :)